# Align Image To Left Of Input Box & Text To The Right

Tags: html, css

I have aligned the image to the left of the input box but the writing is overlapping the image. How do I get around this? The image has been aligned to the left just fine, I just need the input text to be aligned to the right of the image now instead of overlapping

```
CSS
input {
background: url(../../core/images/search.png) no-repeat center left 5px #FFF;
text-align: left;
padding: 5px;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
color: #444;
border: 3px solid #FFF;
outline: none;
border-radius: 3px;
margin: -4px 20px;
position: absolute;
width: 270px;
}

HTML
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="name">
```

Answer (score 1):

give `padding-left` to `input` according to `width` of `image`

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use `padding` ? Have a look:

```
padding-left: 65px;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8JLXj/9/ 

Or `text-indent` :

```
text-indent: 65px;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8JLXj/10/

Answer (score 1):

use text-index property:

```
text-index:(pic\'s width+gap between pics and first letter)px;
```

or you can also use `padding-left:10px;` to create the distance from pic.